# learning c, cygwin gcc can't find my hello.c file

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I am learning c from a book: C programming for the absolute beginner.  Cygwin was recommended.  I installed the basic package. I wrote the basic hello world in notepad.  I have added the bin directory to the path variable.  This is what I get:

```
User@user-be2704c908 ~
$ gcc hello.c
gcc: error: hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Note: I have tried to solve the problem various ways.  Many forums offers similar problems but have found no success. Looked in Cygwin help but is too complicated for a beginner. What would be the best way to learn about this if the beginner book is not helping?

Comment: I've tagged with cygwin. (Apologies, misread the error but I'll leave the cygwin tag in anyway.)

Comment: Are you sure `hello.c` is in the right directory? Do you see it when you type `ls`?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, as you can see from the error message, gcc complains about hello.c not being found.

Comment: You will have to cd to your project directory where hello.c exists..

Answer (score 2):

Save your hello.c in your current working directory. Also make sure permissions of hello.c is 'read' (atleast)  for the user.

Comment: Might want explain how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that notepad saves your `hello.c` file in your cygwin-user's home directory, which is probably something like `C:\cygwin\home\User`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your file is in the directory where you are. Try the `ls` command to list all the files in your current directory.

Moreover, be sure that your filename is `hello.c` and not `hello.c.txt`. You can see that again with the `ls` command.